# append specific text using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

below is my input.

```
)] 'Orac_Read_Wxdm:Oo_trf.v'
)] 'Orac_open_Wxdm:ab_write.v'
)] 'Orac_stak_Wxdm:mnk_opened.v'
```

Output:

```
)] 'Orac_Read_Wxdm:Lnk_Oo_trf.v'
)] 'Orac_open_Wxdm:Lnk_ab_write.v'
)] 'Orac_stak_Wxdm:Lnk_mnk_opened.v'
```

I need the above output using notepad++. 
I need to append 'Lnk_' at specific part of text

Is this possible in notepad++. Any suggestions Please

Comment: How about replace `:` with `:Lnk_`?

Comment: or \_Wxdm: to \_Wxdm:Lnk_ (think simple ;)

Comment: And I'd like to point out that this doesn't seem to need regex at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following Find/Replace pairs:

- Find `:` and Regex Replace with `:Lnk_`
- Find `_Wxdm` and Replace with `_Wxdm:Lnk`